# TCP between two computer in a diffrent network using Java

Tags: java, tcp

I wrote a Server-Client chatprogram that lets you send messages between two Computer in the same Network. Now im trying the get it work if the computer are in diffrent networks. I already cofigured my router to forward request with a cetain port to my pc. I am guessing that the client pc also needs to do this? 
To connect the client I use this code:

```
static Socket smtpSocket = null;
smtpSocket = new Socket();
smtpSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("-Server IP-", Port));
```

Server:

```
echoServer = new ServerSocket();
echoServer.bind(new InetSocketAddress("-Server IP", Port));
```

to send/receive data I use a PrintStream/DataInput Stream on both side:

```
is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
```

But nothing happens.
Do I have to configure the PrintStreams to send Data to the specic Computer?

Comment: If your code works when communicating between two local sessions (on the same computer) then your problem is not within Java (or your implementation) but within your network configuration (or that of the other network). I'd assume the other network does not have the correct port configuration like you think.

Comment: I did not open a Port on the client pc or router. But a message from the client to the server should work anyway right?

Comment: Both computers must be on the same subnet and firewall rules added to allow the traffic.

Comment: Client Outgoing -> Port configured server *should* be fine. @JohnnyV the computers are in different networks so the "subnet" part of that is not true, and the firewall part is also questionable.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson  I'm not assuming that OP knows what 'networks' means and that routers are properly configured.

Comment: Define "nothing happens". No error messages whatsoever?

Comment: @JohnnyV I see no reason to make those assumptions. You're just throwing in confusion, especially when you do not make it obviously clear your reply is based on said assumption.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson we don't know how the routers are configured? maybe there are no routes configured between the two subnets? maybe someone disconnected a cable? maybe the routers have firewalls?  The reality is this could be a dozen things and they're all network related.  Should be moved to Server Fault.

Comment: @JohnnyV I think you're mentioning the wrong person here. My problem is simply with you running with an assumption that OP is non-aware of the fundamental definitions of which they are working, it would be akin to me saying "the second computer needs to be on".